# Exception in thread main java.net.socketexception connection reset when downloading gradle zip file

Tags: android, command-line, build, apk

i want build by android studio project using command prompt but when execute **gradlew.bat** file it start download gradle from this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip but after that it show this Exception **Exception in thread main java.net.socketexception connection reset**

Please help me how to resolve it